# Why do my buttons only work on the first frame of the main timeline in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to code the navigation of a Flash AS3 project in an actionscript file. In the project there are several frames with buttons to navigate through the project. The ones I have coded for the first frame work, but on any other frame they don't.

here is the code:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
public class Main extends MovieClip
{



    public function Main()
    {
        trace("it's working");
        btn_one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,eventResponse1);
        btn_two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,eventResponse2);
        btn_three.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,eventResponse3);
        btn_four.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,eventResponse4);
        btn_five.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,eventResponse5);
        btn_six.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,eventResponse6);


    }

    function eventResponse1(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndStop("game");
    }


    function eventResponse2(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndStop("specimenroom");
    }


    function eventResponse3(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndStop("how");
    }

    function eventResponse4(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndStop("game");
    }


    function eventResponse5(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndStop("feedback");
    }

    function eventResponse6(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndStop("home");
    }


}
}
```

In the code the first five buttons work, but the sixth doesn't. This button is not located on the first frame of the main timeline, it's on the second and third frame. It doesn't work at all. What code is needed to get them to work? Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The button must be present on the frame that the AS3 code gets executed on.

For example, if your button is on frame 2 and your code that tries to add the listener is on frame 1, that will not work.

I assume you are using a Document class, so the same applies. Only what is present on the stage at the time that constructor code runs, is available for you to work with.

What you could do is have a method that adds listeners to the appropriate buttons when you go to that frame.

There are other solutions that would require a more radical change to your current design of using the timeline to change screens, so I suggested the one that would require minimum change.

Because you asked in comments another possible solution is to not navigate through your different screens via timeline frames, but instead do it via code and MovieClip symbols that contain your UI screens. You would just create the instances of the screens in code as needed and handle their handlers appropriately when doing so.

Comment: Thanks! Just to let you know, I'm at the beginning of the project, so I can change the current design at this point. What are other solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

other solution is that make button accessible on first frame and change its alpha to zero so that its not visible. This why u will not have to change the code and just change the time line.